# Is it necessary for dev branch and main branch up to date?

Tags: git

I am confused about some concepts in Git.

I try to use GitHub for my codes.

I have a branch `main` and I treat it as my deployable branch.

Then, I create a `dev` branch from the `main` branch for my development.

My workflow is whenever there are new changes, I will add to `dev` and test it.

If everything is alright, I will merge it to 'main' for deployment.

So, I add some changes to `dev` and make a `pull request` merging it to `main`.

However, I notice the `dev` branch is 1 commit behind `main` after merging. I can see `main` contains one extra commit from the `merge pull request`.

My Questions:

Should I make `dev` branch always up to date regarding to `main` and why?
If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Does `git diff origin/dev..origin/main` return an empty result?

Comment: It might be worth a look at GitHub flow: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/github-flow for a simple branching strategy that would fit your model.  Essentially you are doing that, but reusing an old branch (dev) instead of creating a new feature branch from main for new work.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement I agree the question basically describes GitHub Flow. And, I was about to point out my biggest issue with GitHub Flow (which was deploying from the feature branch), but I can't find that anymore. They must have recently gotten rid of that part of the flow!

Comment: @AndrewMcClement, Thanks for your suggestion. As I want to implement GitHub Action Testing for the `dev` branch, I don't want to delete it once it merged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** In your case, the extra commit is due to merging using `--no-ff` as evidenced by the "merge pull request" message, so you don't *need* to merge that commit back into `dev`.

**Generally:**

Whether you need to merge `main` back down into `dev` depends on *why* `main` is ahead of `dev` by some number of commits. As mentioned in [Sıddık Açıl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177234/gi-is-it-necessary-for-dev-branch-and-main-branch-up-to-date#comment125817298_71177234), after the merge, if the two branches don't have any differences, meaning they differ by commits only, then you don't *need* to bring that commit from `main` back into `dev`. One way to differ in commits only is if you are using `--no-ff` when mergeing `dev` into `main`. That forces the creation of a merge commit even when one isn't necessary. Note if you are using `--no-ff`, then over time you will build up additional merge commits on `main` that aren't in `dev`, so next time you'll have 2 commits, then the time after you'll have 3 commits, etc. (Unless you delete `dev` and re-create it from `main`, or just reset it to `main`, after every deployment, in which case that number will never get higher than 1.)

However, immediately after the merge, if `git diff origin/dev..origin/main` does have differences, then there must be changes on `main` that were never merged into `dev`. In that case you probably should merge `main` back into `dev` to keep it up to date with those changes. That being said, the *better* time to do that would have been immediately after new commits went directly to `main`, because if you wait until afterward it's likely that you tested something different than you deployed. Note the first time you have a hotfix into `main`, you will bring all of those extra merge commits from the PRs back into `dev` along with it, and that's fine. Just don't be surprised when you see it! (This won't happen if you happen to reset `dev` to `main` right after deployments.)

**To summarize some rules of thumb:**

1. If you add changes directly to `main`, then merge `main` back into `dev` ASAP.
2. After merging `dev` into `main`, as long as the two branches diff is empty, it's OK to have extra commits on `main`.

**Side Note:** I like using `--no-ff` in this application so I can see all the Production deployments with a `--first-parent` view. Some people prefer to instead allow fast-forward merges and tag each production deployment, and then compare a tag with the previous tag to obtain the same information. (I actually use `--no-ff` and still tag). It comes down to personal taste.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and it turns out what I want is a fast-forward merge. Also, I am expecting the `GitHub web UI` to be defaulted as fast-forward merge but it does not. It provide 3 options but none of it is a fast-forward merge but you can still make a fast-forward merge with CLI which coexist with the protected branch option.

Comment: @ikhvjs GitHub has a "rebase and fast-forward" merge option, but AFAIK there is no option for doing the regular Git default merge, which is "fast-forward if possible otherwise create a merge commit". Even from the CLI the [`-m` merge option](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_merge) still [uses `--no-ff`](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/merging-a-pull-request).

Comment: @ikhvjs if new commits on `dev` are all linear, you *could* use "rebase and ff" option, but it's risky in general for long-lived branches because you'd have to confirm each time that you don't have new merge commits on `dev`. (And you'd pretty much have to  reset `dev` afterwards.) I think the only way to get what you desire is to merge `dev` into `main` yourself locally, then give your user permission to bypass branch protection (or completely disable it) temporarily, push out `main`, then re-enable the protection.

Comment: After you created a pull request, you can still make a fast-forward merge with `CLI` like `git merge dev` which coexist with the GitHub protected branch option. I also tested it and it works. related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906599/14032355

Comment: @ikhvjs Are you saying, from the GitHub CLI, if you did `gh pr merge -m` it would create a merge commit, but if you do `git merge` it will use the default behavior, and it will still let you push that out when branch protection is on?

Comment: I am talking about normal shell script with git `git merge dev`. Yes, you can still push the branch when the branch protection is on, but you must create a pull request in the first place, otherwise it won't allow you to pass.

Comment: @ikhvjs OK, good to know. I didn't know you could push to a protected branch like that in GitHub. I don't know that I'd setup my repo to allow that, but if all the checks are in place I guess it makes sense. I mostly use AzureDevOps and AFAIK that isn't a thing. I like that you can achieve what you want without messing around with permissions. In AzureDevOps AFAIK it's not even possible to do a fast-forward merge without potentially rebasing first.

Comment: Yes. I am happy it works but I do think GitHub should provide an option in the UI with fast-forward merge for people to choose.

Comment: @ikhvjs I agree. Bitbucket has it and GitLab has a setting to only allow ff merges. It would be nice if GitHub and AzDO offered similar functionality. Kind of funny they don't offer the default Git merge strategy. ;)